# Searchbox text and border colors not recognizing CSS changes

Tags: css

The home page´s searchbox  in our site doesn´t show properly even when the changes and modifications under the "System>Configuration>"OurTheme"options>Theme Design" Values are set to different colors. After refreshing the page, searchbox keeps the same appearance. I know it´s not recognizing the changes made, any ideas?

I leave a screenshot on how does the box looks like all the time, customers keep complaining it can´t be seen. Please HELP

[image: Searchbox]

Comment: Share your url?

Comment: https://troquer.com.mx/tienda/ 
(strange fact, the searchbox after entering any section looks fine, it´s just failing on the homepage)

Comment: Actually what is the problem

Comment: When trying to make a search at the homepage, text is almost invisible. i tried changing color and opacity values under magento´s backend configuration settings, but doesn´t recognize changes made.

Comment: header#header .form-search input {
   color: #000 !important;
 } add this in your css

Comment: Thanks !!! worked perfectly, turns out, we have 2 different themes working on different pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

In your css add below code

```
header#header .form-search input { color: #000 !important; }
```

or find this

```
header#header .form-search input {
    width: 89%;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 2px;
    transition: border-color .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: border-color .8s ease;
    -webkit-transition: border-color .8s ease;
    -o-transition: border-color .8s ease;
}
```

and command or delete color

```
 color: #F5F5F5;
```

I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

In your skin's CSS file, add the following to the bottom:

```
header#header .form-search input { color: #000 !important; }
```

(Converting Kothari's comment into a answer:)